# How to check element in a array in PERL with grep?

Tags: arrays, perl

I would like to check if a element is in the array?

```
my %hash = (
 Value1 => ['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2'],
); #/!\NOT ARRAY

my @table = ( '10.0.0.6', '10.0.0.1');
```

**Pseudo-code**

```
my $i = 0;
if( grep { $table[0] eq $_ } eq $hash{"Value1[]"} ) {
 print "Find!!!";
 $i++; #true
}
if( grep { $table[1] eq $_ } eq $hash{"Value1[]"} ) {
 print "Find!!!";
 $i++; #true
}

if ( $i = 2) {
 print "It is perfect. 0% difference between table and hash{"Value1"}";
}
if ( $i = 1) {
 print "It is middle. 50% difference between table and hash{"Value1"}";
}
if ( $i = 0) {
 print "It is bad. 100% difference between table and hash{"Value1"}";
}
```

1. How to convert hash to array ? [Use grep in PERL](http://perlmaven.com/filtering-values-with-perl-grep)
2. I'm not sure for grep syntax "$_"??

I'm only a beginner in PERL.

Thx very much.

Comment: `if ( grep { $table[0] eq $_ } @{ $hash{Value1} } ) { ... }`

Comment: I just test your fix and it's work !! Thank you. Now i will be able to improve my program.

Answer (score 0):

```
for my $ip (@ips_to_find) {
   for my $key (keys(%hash)) {
      print("$ip in $key\n")
         if grep { $_ eq $ip } @{ $hash{$key} };
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce code by using loop for searching element.

```
my %hash = ('Value1' => ['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2'] ); 
    my @table = ( '10.0.0.6', '10.0.0.1');

    my $i = 0;
    for my $val (@table) {
        if (grep $_ eq $val, @{ $hash{'Value1'} })
       {
            print "Find!!!\n";
        $i++;
        }
    }

    if ( $i == 2) {
     print "It is perfect. 0% difference between table and hash{'Value1'}";
    }
    elsif ( $i == 1) {
     print "It is middle. 50% difference between table and hash{'Value1'}";
    }
    elsif ( $i == 0) {
     print "It is bad. 100% difference between table and hash{'Value1'}";
    }
```

Output

```
G:\Study\Perl Arsenal>perl temp.pl
Find!!!
It is middle. 50% difference between table and hash{'Value1'}
G:\Study\Perl Arsenal>
```